# Excel - Only format column if TODAY

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have been trying to do this myself for a good few weeks now but it seems I do require some expertise here!

As I state in the Title, I'm trying to format duplicate values ONLY if date (located C1:AG1) =today. The values per day are in cells C2-AG28, the table of reference is AI2:28.

I don't have enough reputation to submit an attachment so I hope this is enough information for someone to shed a light on this.

Comment: Why is this tagged with "duplicates"?

Comment: What's the actual business intent you have? Do you want to flag duplicates so that you have a list that you can use for some other purpose? Reason I ask is that a PivotTable may very well be a great solution, depending on your exact problem. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: Hi Jeffrey,

The sheet contains the asset numbers of office equipment, laptops in this instance.  The sheet is an overview for 1 month that shows which colleague currently has which laptop. So say Mike (Name is in A2:A28) has a laptop from the 2nd - 6th of December (D1:H1) the laptop asset number would be in the rows below this, D2:H2 (or any of the 28 available rows, depending on where his name in A). 
AI2:28 contains all laptops asset numbers, whether or not they are available.  This column should function as a quick reference to see which assets are currently available (TODAY).

Comment: To elaborate further, and to answer questions elsewhere in this thread:

One entry can only be in one row for a day as this is regarding actual physical items and can only be given out once for that day, if that makes sense. So one column (= 1 date) will always have an unique value.  However at the moment when say today is 2-DEC, Mary had the same laptop Mike had on the 1st of December, using regular CF, formatting duplicate values, it will be formatted and results will not be accurate.

You could possibly delete all entries <TODAY to prevent this, but I want to avoid this at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting.

Click cell `C1` and click *conditional formatting* and then *new rule*.

For the rule, use a formula to determine which cells to format and use this formula:

```
= C$1=TODAY()
```

Change the format to whatever you want and then apply this rule to the desired range (`C1:AG28`).

Comment: That highlights the entire column where $1 = today.  However I need to conditionally format the duplicate value (containing a number, not a date) in a column, ie C2:C28 if C1 = today where the duplicate can be found in AI2:28, which should also be formatted in case of a duplicate value. 

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Clear any existing CF from the relevant range, select it and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(C$1=TODAY(),COUNTIF(C:C,C1)>1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Comment: Not sure why I can't get this to work.  Will try this on a new sheet as the current is full of CFs.  However, have prioritised this one over the rest so should still.  Will try again and get back to you.

Comment: 01/11/2017 and so forth.  This date format does respond to another rule in the sheet that uses the TODAY function.

Answer (score 0):

Select the range `C2:AG28` and create a new Conditional Formatting rule using a formula. The formula should be entered as follows:

```
=AND(C$1=TODAY(),COUNTIF(C$2:C$28,C2)>1)
```

The first part, identifying the column containing today's date in the first row is self-explanatory. The `countif` section of this formula works by identifying only those values which appear more than once in the column (e.g. having a count > 1). The way we limit this to a particular column, rather than the entire table, is by omitting the `$` in front of the column in the address.